# Is it possible to convert .ter to .pdf file?

Tags: pdf, toad

I have a ER diagram generated from TOAD for mysql. Is it possible to convert the .ter to .pdf?? I couldnt find anything useful on the net. Any suggestions ...

Comment: Can you print from toad? A PDF printer might work if you can

Comment: Check this out: http://tda.inside.quest.com/thread.jspa?threadID=9961.
Apparently the guy converts first to .mdi